# Describe the past years in the diagram,use the past tense or present tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I need to write a composition according to a diagram,and I don't know whether to use the past tense or present tense.

> The figures of year 1 and year 2 **shows** an upward trend while year
> 3 **saw** an opposite trend.

Is the tense right?

Comment: ***figures*** is plural, so the first verb must be ***show***, not ***shows***. Juxtaposing ***show*** with significantly more metaphoric ***to see*** looks like poor style to me - perhaps somewhat "forced" by the switch from using a ***figure*** of a year as a subject to using the ***year*** itself as a subject. So I'd try rephrasing to avoid that anyway, but if you stick with those two different "slightly incompatible" subjects, you've got yet another "awkward choice" regarding ***sees*** or ***saw***. Both are grammatical, but they're both potentially awkward whichever you choose. Rephrase!

Comment: As the proverbial Irishman says when you ask him for directions to your intended destination: *"If I wanted to go there, I wouldn't start from here!"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The figures of year 1 and year 2 shows an upward trend while year 3
> saw an opposite trend.

As pointed out in comments, "*shows*" should be the singular "*show*".  However, yes, the use of tense is correct.  Even though year 1 and year 2 are in the past, the figures representing them do currently exist (and are presumably right there in front of the reader) and you correctly use the present tense when mentioning them.  You also correctly switched to past tense when referring directly to "year 3" as it is something that existed in the past